# Foursquare API venues: only 60% matches our database

Tags: database, match, foursquare

We have our own existing venue database we want to match with venues from the Foursquare Places API. The purpose of this is to retrieve and display certain info and content from Foursquare.

Currently we're having trouble matching the Foursquare venues with our own venues, only 60% matches. We pass the following parameters:

- ll: latitude, longitude of the venue
- query: name of the venue
- categoryId: "4bf58dd8d48988d1fa931735" - ID of venue category
- intent: browse
- locale: en
- radius: 100

We also tried the intent=match parameter but that gave us even less matches. Is there anything we can change that would improve our matching percentage or is this the best it can get?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that foursquare's database is more or less user created. You have to account for user error, category mismatch or even the location data being off. Also even when using the FourSquare app or Swarm, all venues in the immediate area don't always show up in the results.

Example, searching for a Starbucks sometimes includes ones that may far, far away. The order of the the results are another story, it may not be distance, their search uses other factors relating to user preferences and popularity.

Sorry if this is not much of an answer but from using the apps and the api, I believe you'll have a hard time getting close to 100% without a lot of data manipulation and creative calls to their search.

Answer (score 0):

To get a higher match rate use the `venues/search` api and only use parameters for `ll` and `query`.

Since Foursquare has such a deep category taxonomy, I would avoid using the `categoryId` parameter unless you are 100% certain it matches with what Foursquare has. Also, I wouldn't use `intent=browse` for any matching. By leaving out the intent param it will default to `intent=checkin`, which will be better for fuzzy matching.

If you need precision at the expense of match rate, you can set `intent=match`. This parameter is very sensitive but can accept things like phone number and address as well. This is great for when you don't have a lat/lng but since you do I wouldn't bother with this.